# Incorrect products on site

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Yesterday while creating products on the site in Hybris via Administration console  I accidentally fired an INSERT_UPDATE instead of UPDATE thus creating multiple extra products.I removed staged versions but one thing is strange the online versions are having blank catalog versions so when I filter via the catalog say XyzCatalog the catalog is null.Can it cause some issue to have such empty products in production

Answer (score 0):

If the catalog version is empty.It won't show in frontend.

Comment: Thanks but why is the catalog version blank in such a case